# Calculate $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

## Question

$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}=34$ and $x$ is a natural number. Find the value of $x^3 +  \frac{1}{x^3}$ and choose the correct answer from the following options:

1. 198
2. 216
3. 200
4. 186

---

## What I have did yet

I tried to find the value of $x + \frac{1}{x}$. Here are my steps to do so:
$$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 34$$
$$\text{Since}, (x+\frac{1}{x})^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+\frac{1}{x})^2-2=34$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+\frac{1}{x})^2=34+2 = 36$$
$$\Rightarrow x+\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{36}=6$$

I have calculated the value of $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is $6$. I do not know what to do next.

Comment: What happens when you cube $x+\frac 1x$?

Comment: Note that $x$ cannot be a "natural number", and you are missing squaring/taking the square root in some of your calculations. You are, though on the right track, but you need to take a little more care.

Comment: Sorry, but according to the question $x$ will be a natural number.

Comment: If $x$ is a natural number other than $1$ then $x^2+\frac 1{x^2}$ cannot be an integer. And $x\neq 1$ is easy to check. It doesn't actually matter very much here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint $(x+\frac{1}{x})^3=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+3(x+\frac{1}{x})$ also $(x+\frac{1}{x})=6$ not $36$ you seem to have typed an incorrect calculation.

Comment: Thank you! You are really helpful. I will accept your answer soon. Sorry but I cannot upvote your answer. I don't have much reputations.

Comment: I have edited the question. The procedure to find $x+\frac{1}{x}$ has been corrected. Thanks to @Archis-Welankar for his help.

Comment: You are welcome! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

$$(x+\frac{1}{x}) = x^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

But it should read

$$(x+\frac{1}{x})^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Then we obtain $x+\frac{1}{x}=6.$

From $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}=34$ we obtain

$(1) \quad x^3+\frac{1}{x}=34 x$

and

$(2) \quad x+\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{34}{x}.$

If we add (1) and (2) we get

$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=33(x+\frac{1}{x}).$$

Ans so

$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=6 \cdot 33=198.$$

Remark : if $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}=34$, then $x$ can not be a natural number !

Answer (score 1):

Let have a look at this: [finding $x^6+y^6$ given $x+y$ and $xy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3897042/399263)

$$U_n=x^n+\frac 1{x^n}$$

$s=x+\frac 1x=U_1$ and $p=x\times\frac 1x=1$

also we have $\begin{cases}U_2=34\\U_0=x^0+\frac 1{x^0}=1+1=2\end{cases}$

We have the relation $$U_{n+1}=U_1U_n-U_{n-1}$$

$U_2=U_1^2-U_0\implies U_1^2=34+2=36\implies U_1=\pm 6$

And $U_3=U_1U_2-U_1=\pm 6(34-1)=\pm 198\quad$ (among proposed answers the positive one fits).

Note: *$x$ cannot be integer, since $x+\frac 1x=\pm 6\iff x=\pm(3\pm 2\sqrt{2})$*

This method can be generalized to most $x^n+y^n$ types of questions.